# Data doesn't show in console.log but renders fine in template

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component in which I make an axois call to get all employees data, store it in an array, and display it in a table. That works just fine.

The behavior that I'm confused with however can be seen in the getEmployees() method below, where I have console.log(this.employees);

When I check the console, the object that is being returned there is blank and doesn't have any employees data, even though the same data object, when iterated through in the template, is displaying all the employees data.

Have a look at the code:

```
<template>
    <b-table striped hover :items="employees"></b-table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                employees: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            getEmployees() {
                axios.get('/api/employees')
                    .then(response => this.employees = response.data)

                console.log(this.employees);
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.getEmployees()
        }
    }
</script>
```

The reason I did console.log there was because I wanted to traverse that data and format all the salaries data within that array to a money format (i.e. comma after thousands, currency symbol, etc.)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope for assigning values to this.employees is within promise's .then() method. Try expanding your arrow function and then within .then() method put the console.log() call.

```
<template>
    <b-table striped hover :items="employees"></b-table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                employees: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            getEmployees() {
                axios.get('/api/employees')
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.employees = response.data;
                        console.log(this.employees);
                      }
                   )


            }
        },

        created() {
            this.getEmployees()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Within .then() you should do the rest of changes after.

Comment: Oh wow thank you. This worked. I'll accept the answer as soon as S.O. lets me.

Comment: I (incorrectly) assumed that due to the reactive state-management nature of Vue, I would be able to access its values once they are set. I imagine that in general it is probably best practice to get into the habit of dealing with the axois response the way you have.

Comment: @Kopty, problem is that .then() is called asynchronously, after ajax call  is resolved, and code outside / after `.then()` is called synchronously and won't wait for code within `.then()` to be execuded. 

You could also `watch` property this.employees for changes, instead of changing it within .then() handle, but keep in mind that this might overload performance.